# Linq to entities - Query elements where List<string> property has at least an element that matches other element in an in memory list

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

A bit of a **context** for the problem:

I have an entity (Person) in my database that has a one to many relationship with another (Phone).

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public virtual List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    }

    public class Phone
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

Secondly I'm receiving a filter that includes a list of strings.

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to get from the DB all the Persons that have at least a PhoneNumber that matches (by like) any of the filter's phone numbers.

So far I've tryed this:

```
var query = _dbContext.Person
                .Include(x => x.PhoneNumbers)
                .AsNoTracking();
                .Where(x => x.Phones
                             .Any(y => filter.Phones
                                             .Any(z => y.PhoneNumber.Contains(z))));
```

This query throws an error:

*The LINQ expression {my expression here} could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."*

**Thanks you!**

Comment: You cannot use with EF Core LINQ operators over in-memory collections, except `Contains` method. `filter.Phones.Any` is not translatable. Only dynamic predicate building can help in such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a standardized format for your recorded phone numbers (I.e. strip all separators and include a standard area code etc.) then you can format your search list of phone numbers to conform to the format and use:

```
.Where(x => x.Phones.Any(y => filter.Phones.Contains(y.PhoneNumber)));
```

The issue is that you cannot apply a Linq2Entity `Any` against the in-memory collection. You can use `Contains` against the collection but the phone numbers would have to match exactly. (so no inner `LIKE` type comparison)

If you have a reasonable number of search phone numbers and want to do the `LIKE` type search across the phone numbers then you can leverage LinqKit's PredicateBuilder to prepare a suitable condition. This requires marking the query as "Expandable" so the dynamic predicate can be built.

```
var query = _dbContext.Person
    .Include(x => x.PhoneNumbers)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .AsExpandable();

if (filter.Phones.Any())
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Person>();
    foreach(var phone in filter.Phones)
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Phones.Any(p => p.Contains(phone)));
    query = query.Where(predicate);
}
```